# Angular filter in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a filter that works fine when i have only one row in my table. But how to filter at a specific row (index) when i have multiple row ? In this example i want to filter by country id to display specific cities :

My Html :

```
 <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
     <select ng-model="country.id" ng-change="selectCountry($index,country.id)"
                                            ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countries">
                                        <option value="">Country</option>
                                    </select>

    <select ng-model="city.id" ng-change="selectCity($index,city.id)"
                                            ng-options="city.id as city.name for city in cities" | filter:filterByCities>
                                        <option value="">City</option>
                                    </select>
</tr>
```

Ng-Controller :

```
$scope.countries = {
     {"id" : 1, "name" : "USA" },
     {"id" : 2, "name" : "CANADA" }
 }

 $scope.cities= {
     {"id" : 1, "name" : "MIAMI" },
     {"id" : 2, "name" : "TORONTO" }
 }


$scope.selectCountry = function (index, value) {

                if (value ==1) {
                    $scope.selectedCities = [1, 2];
                }
                else if (value == 2) {
                    $scope.selectedCities = [3, 4];
                }
                $scope.filterByCities = function (type) {
                    return ($scope.selectedCities.indexOf(type.id,index) !== -1);
                };
            }
```

But the filter work for all my rows in my table, not only for the row where i select the filter.

Thanks for you help

Comment: `$index` will be different with filters and can't be used. No table shown here so not really clear what problem is there. Also should show sample data since `indexOf` is probably not right

Comment: I'm using ng-repeat obviously

Comment: That doesn't clarify much or outline specific problem. Suggest you create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). Also please note any errors thrown in browser console

Comment: When i select a country, i want to filter by cities in the same row when i select the country.

Comment: Need some data samples and a demo would be best place to do that

Comment: Why don't you just put a country id on your cities and then filter on the chosen country id?

Comment: All the code is there ! I just need to find a way to filter tje datas within a specific row (index), because so far the filter is applied in all my Rows. The actual code works but for all my rows. ex . Now, If i select a country from my 3eme row, the filter is applied in 1,2,3,4 rows but it should only be applied in my 3eme

Comment: Amy Blankenship : The datas comes from a database in two different tables

Comment: Why doesn't the database have the relationship specified? Relational design 101,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code doesn't make a lot of sense. I propose you those changed where you have a third array that correspond to the model of your rows.

You don't want to have selectedCities to be the same for all your rows. Each input cities in your table should be filter by the input of the country on the same row. You need a model to keep track of those change, this is the goal of the `rows` array:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.rows = [{
      countryId : 4, cityId : 2 
  }, {}, {}];

  $scope.countries = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "USA"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "CANADA"
  }];

  $scope.cities = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "MIAMI",
    "countryId": 1
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "VANCOUVER",
    "countryId": 4
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "TORONTO",
    "countryId": 4
  },{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "LOS ANGELES",
    "countryId": 1
  }];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Country
      </th>
      <th>
        City
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td>
        <select ng-model="row.countryId" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countries">
          <option value="">Country</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="row.cityId" ng-options="city.id as city.name for city in cities | filter:{countryId:row.countryId}">
          <option value="">City</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code i have was up voted to 16 in one of the discussions in sof. I took it and i wanted it to change it to make it work for multiple rows. Thanks for your example !

Comment: do you remember that post? do you have the link? maybe I can help you understand why it was bad ;)

Comment: I will find it and send it to you :). But what about if i want to keep country.id as country.name ? instead of  country as country.name.

Comment: Cyril Gandon, you example doesn't work for me finally, that's why i started using the other approach. I will need this : select ng-model="row.id" and not  ng-model="row.country" because i want to load the id not the country object

Comment: Updated to stock country id and not country object

Comment: Cyril Gandon : That's exactly what i was looking for. Thank you sir :)